# Is "whitespace" one word or two?

Tags: hyphenation

I tend to write "whitespace" to talk about any negative space in type (in particular, the characters that cause it in ASCII & Unicode).

However I have also seen it written "white-space" and "white space".

I presume it doesn't matter, but are there any conventions that can guide my usage?

Comment: If there were ever a word that needed a space between its parts to make it complete, it's "white space".

Comment: As the question that this is marked as a duplicate of does not directly address this question (although there is an answer there), I'll summarise it here for the record: In design, it is usually "[white space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_space_%28visual_arts%29)", but in computing (referring to textual characters used for spacing) it is usually "[whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)"